# Compare the position of the words in two strings

Tags: python-3.x, list, linked-list

I have a task: Compare the position of the two input strings (the strings is represented as List or Linked List). I'm using Python 3.9.5

For example:

A = ['I', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'student']

B = ['I', 'am', 'student']

=> match 3/5

I have tried many way but it isn't correct.

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Please post what you attempted; someone may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: What does this have to do with a `linked-list`?

Comment: What if there are duplicates?  Why is the second number 5?

Comment: What if A has words not in B *and* B has words not in A?

Answer (score 0):

```
A = ['I', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'student']
B = ['I', 'am', 'student']
point=0
for value in B:
    if value in A:
        point+=1
print(" Matches: ",point,"/",len(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways one using set intersection and the other using list comprehension:

```py
A = ['I', 'am', 'a', 'good', 'student']
B = ['I', 'am', 'student']

print(f"matches: {len(set(A).intersection(set(B)))}/{len(A)}") # or len(set(A)&set(B))
print(f"matches: {sum([1 for x in A if x in B])}/{len(A)}")
```